# Need help getting regex to get something between 2 unrelated strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out how to make a certain regex, even with the help of a regex generator.

I need to get exactly the string between (including spaces): `</a>:` and `&nbsp;`.

If nobody wants to get a headache over doing this, I can understand.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and your expected output. The way you've worded this it doesn't make sense.  Also, I like to use http://regexhero.net/ when working with regular expressions.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting in the question.

Comment: I'm assuming it's `some data ": " <some string and etc. " " somedata` They want to get the whole `": " <some string and etc. " "`

Comment: @Abody97 If only you haven't removed anything important.

Comment: I failed my question quite badly, so I'll remove it after it's answered, I suppose.

Comment: @Maarten: Do you expect the quotes to be part of your string, or did you use them only as delimiters?

Comment: @MaartenBoogaard: There is no reason to remove it. If you want to improve it, you can [edit] it

Comment: @Bergi, I expected that there wouldn't be any special markup editing my quotes, so that it would come out unchanged as I had input it. Apparently it got converted to markup/half code instead, or something like that.

Comment: What if there are several `&nbsp;` in the string? do you need to stop at the first one or the last one?

Comment: The first one. It finds it in a small ajax page, so there's no chance there'll be more of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match this: `/(?<=<\/a>: ).*(?=&nbsp;)/`

However, JavaScript does not support lookbehind, so you are bound to be using [matching groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
var regex = /<\/a>: (.*?)&nbsp;/;
var match = myString.match(regex);
if (match)
    return match[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does it return an array? (match[i]?)

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the [String `match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Alright, regardless, works perfect! Thank you very much for your effort. I can't vote your answer useful because of my low reputation, but you bet that it was extremely useful.